# Mapping collection of enum in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, collections, enums, nhibernate-mapping

I have a class with collection of enums:

Class1.cs

```
public enum Language
{
    Serbian = 1,
    Croatian,
    Ukrainian,
}

public class Class1
{
   private IList<Language> m_languages = new List<Language>();
   public virtual IList<Language> Languages
   {
          get { return m_languages; }
          set { m_languages = value; }
   }
}
```

What is the content of mapping file for this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/sean_chambers/archive/2008/04/06/mapping-an-collection-of-enums-with-nhibernate.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you may want to consider something a little 'smarter' than enums; take for instance Fabio's [Well Known Instance Type](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/08/from-db-to-ram-wellknowinstancetype.html) example - I find myself using these all the time for (relatively) static data.