# nHibernate code mapping for enum collection

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm getting started with nHibernate code mapping and I'm stuck on mapping a collection of enums.

*(Note, this question is similar to [Mapping collection of enum in NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412132/mapping-collection-of-enum-in-nhibernate) but different in that I want to map using code mappings.)*

I have an entity "Role" which has a collection of "Permissions", which Permissions is an enum.

The old xml mapping for this is:

```
<set name="Permissions" cascade="none" table="role_permissions">
  <key column="role_id" />
  <element column="permission_id" type="MyApp.Permissions, MyApp" />
</set>
```

And I'm trying to map in code like this, but I get an exception:

```
Set(x => x.PermissionCollection, m => { },
  r => r.Element(e =>
  {
    e.Column("permission_id");
    e.Type<Permissions>();
  }));
```

Exception thrown is

```
Expected type implementing IUserType or IType.
Parameter name: persistentType
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
Set(x => x.PermissionCollection, m =>
{
    m.Key(km => km.Column("role_id"));
    m.Table("role_permissions");
},
r => r.Element(e => e.Column("permission_id")));
```

Comment: Hmm, that got me past the initial configuration, but when trying to use the Role entity I'm getting an "Invalid Cast" exception.  It might be a different problem, I'm not sure which property is causing the cast exception.

Comment: Could you provide your Role class.

Comment: In my test app this mapping persists and loads entity without any errors. Interestingly, what code throws this exception?

Comment: This is strange:  when I try the app again, i get a different exception.  This time during the mapping configuration I get "Could not determine type for: MyApp.Role, MyApp, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(id)".  I think you've given me the answer to my first problem, but looks like I've got some more work to do.

Comment: It ended up being my version column - my code had it as "long?" but the configuration must have been trying to use an int.